# Deploy Approval Process using Mavensmate

Tags: deployment, approval-process, mavensmate

I'm trying to deploy an approval process to another production org using Mavenmate deploy to server. My problem is that the approval process I'm trying to deploy has an assigned user in the approval steps. When I try to deploy that user doesn't exist in the production org I'm trying to deploy (of course). How can I edit the package.xml to have another user on that approval process?
Do I need to use other tool?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the same problems even if you try to deploy using any other tools .The error has nothing to do with Mavensmate .The possible way to solve will be to change the user in source instance to match to the PROD instance .

Once deployed you can obviously change manually the User .

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I ended up using Ant-Migration Tool and changing the user  between retrieve and deploy processes. Then I could deploy sucessfully the approval process.

Comment: Cool ..You could have done same using mavens as well .When you deployed you could have changed User .This was nothing specific to Mavensmate .

Comment: Yeah I know it's more specific to me :D Mavenmate is an awesome tool, and that's why I wanted to figure out a way to do this process using it, love working with it. But I couldn't find out how to edit in between retrieve and deploy processes. Oh well, at least I got it to work with ANT.